# Ionic 4 problem with iOS and Android loading UI component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Currently, I'm developing a mobile app using ionic 4 with angular js as backend. I was wondering about the orientation of UI components on both Android and iOS because whenever I run the application, the placement of **ion-icon** and **ion-input** are different to both device type.

This is my code snippet for login form

```
   <ion-item>
     <ion-label position="floating">Username</ion-label>
     <ion-input clearInput type="text"></ion-input>
     <ion-icon name="contact" slot="start" align-self-center></ion-icon>
   </ion-item>

   <ion-item>
       <ion-label position="floating">Password</ion-label>
       <ion-input type="password" clearInput></ion-input>
       <ion-icon name="key"slot="start" align-self-center></ion-icon>
   </ion-item>
 </ion-card>
```

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: it's because your are using (position="floating") on ion-label
You can put ion-icon inside ion-label

Comment: even if i changed its position the problem still exist.

Comment: try to remove position prop. My app is working.